# How to use spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure with a multiple ClientRegistrationRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have an application, lets call it AppOne, that uses `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` to configure the login to AppOne. `@EnableWebSecurity` is on. As I understand it, the autoconfigure will create a `@Bean` of type `ClientRegistrationRepository` with some info found in `application.propertes`. Example below:

```
security.oauth2.resource.id=${azure.clientId}
security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/{SomeTenant}.com/discovery/keys
```

This works as it should. Now I want to create a `WebClient` that should authenticate against an external application, lets call it `ExternalApp`. For that I want to create a class that looks something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ExternalAppOAuth2Configuration {
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService;*/

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(){
        var authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        var authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, oAuth2AuthorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean("externalAppClient")
    public WebClient externalAppWebClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager){
        String url = "someURL";

        var client = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(manager);
        client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("externalApp");

        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .filter(client)
                .filters(x -> x.add(client))
                .defaultHeaders(this::defaultHeaders)
                .build();
        }
}
```

However, I want the `ClientRegistrationRepository` in the class above to use a different set of credentials than the one used for login to AppOne. So in my `application.properties`, I define the credentials like so:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.externalApp.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.externalApp.client-id={CLIENT_ID}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.externalApp.client-secret={CLIENT_SECRET}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.externalApp.scope={SCOPE}
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.externalApp.token-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Now I was under the impression that since I specify the registration name as `externalApp`, that these credentials should only apply when I do something like this: `client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("externalApp")`, but it seems that it completely overwrites the login flow of AppOne, as instead of being met with a login screen I am simply met with a `503 Service Unavailable` screen. Is it not possible to have several configuration of `ClientRegistrationRepository` and use them in different places? Have I missed something else important?

Comment: I don't have a full example for you but I want to let you know that Spring Oauth2 is deprecated and it is not worth to invest time into it. Please follow the migration guide at https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/Home.html

Comment: @Palbo did you figured out the issue ? I'm also facing the same issue.